# Using for loop to set ranges of column widths in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, range

[image]

I want to be able to use some sort of for loop to set column widths in an excel sheet so I don't have to type out each column I want to change the width of. In the case of this picture, I want all black columns to have a width of 0.92, green to be 0.83, and orange to be 7.29, and I want these to continue past what I've shown here for a set range. Below is the general code I used, but like I said, I don't want to have to type out every column to change the width.

```
sub Set_Column_Width

   Range("E:E, I:I, M:M, Q:Q, U:U, Y:Y, AC:AC, AG:AG, AK:AK, AO:AO, AS:AS, AT:AT, AX:AX").ColumnWidth = 0.92
  Range("G:G,K:K,O:O,S:S").ColumnWidth = 0.83
   Range("F:F, H:H, J:J, L:L").ColumnWidth = 7.29

End sub
```

Comment: Is there any rules you could use for this? i.e. what determines which column has what width? Is it the colour or is there a pattern?

Comment: sorry the color was just to better highlight what I was trying to do...its the pattern I'm trying to loop not the color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a pattern, black-orange-green-orange you can loop so.

```
for i = [first column] to [last column] step 4
     Columns(i).ColumnWidth = 0.92
     Columns(i+1).ColumnWidth = 7.29
     Columns(i+2).ColumnWidth = 0.83
     Columns(i+3).ColumnWidth = 7.29
next i
```

Comment: This is better than mine if you change `[]` to `()` and use `i`, `i+1`, `i+2`, `i+3` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Columns(index)`

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 5 To 105 Step 4
    Columns(i).Columwidth = 0.92
next i

For i = 6 To 106 Step 2
    Columns(i).Columwidth = 7.29
next i

For i = 7 To 107 Step 4
    Columns(i).Columwidth = 0.83
next i
```

The other way would be to determine the width based on the index

```
For i = 5 To 100
    'find you what width this column should have
    Columns(i).Columnwidth = x
next i
```

This is assuming the widths are not defined by the colors but by their position

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure what those colors are, it would be easy enough to find out. If the entire column is the same color, you could just loop through the columns and look at row 1. Something like

```
for i = 1 to 1000 'or whatever your last column is
    if cells(1, i).interior.color = rgb(255, 0, 0) then 'red, for example
        cells(1, i).columnwidth = 0.83 'or whatever the column width needs to be here
    else if cells(1, i).interior.color = rgb(...) then 'next color
        cells(1, i).columnwidth = ... 'etc.
    end if
next i
```

Comment: I like this answer, as it takes the color into consideration. It *looks* like OP's columns follow a pattern, but there are no guarantees so I'd go with this one.

Comment: @BruceWayne. Presumably the OP doesn't want to manually do the colouring and then use a macro to do the widths. Oh, the joys of interpreting ambiguous client briefs :)

Comment: Exactly. It's not clear if the spreadsheet truly is colored or if the color was added to illustrate a patter.